# C# parsing part of a string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

WE have an application that prints out a log line.  Within the log lines we also print out the fully syncML Payload in xml.  I need to parse out just the syncML payloads.  The actual xml and strip everything else out.

Log line looks like this.

```
`2016-01-06T15:13:45.188-0500 [DEBUG] {} Logger
[{{Correlation,(longID)}{Uri,POST (post
URL)}{host,(HOST)}{userID,(userID)}}] - request class SyncML: <?xml
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?></ns3:SyncML>`
```

My regex for the request class is as follows.

```
 Regex request = new Regex(@"request class SyncML");
   String line;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
    if(req.Success)
     {
         Match req = request.Match(line);
         string s = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("<?xml "));
     }
   }
```

After the `request.Match(line)`, in VS it shows the full line.  So I know the Match is a truly a success.

However, when I do `line.SubString(line.IndexOF...` I get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  When I checked print out indexOf it's -1.

Perhaps I am using this wrong.  I guess my question is what do I need to do to just strip out everything before

Comment: Can you add more of the log?  Enough so that both the line, and the <?xml are showing?

Comment: The little space "<?xml " could be the culprit, try to do "<?xml" instead

Comment: You're regex ("request class wnimo.SyncML") is not present in the sample log line.  Try "request class SyncML", or better yet drop RegEx and simply do `line.IndexOf("request class SyncML")` in an `if` statement.

Comment: Your code does not look like it would compile to me... you use the variable `req` before it is declared.  Is it declared before in some other way? if so how?

Comment: So I updated my Regex.  Still didn't work.  I removed the space out of the <?xml.  Still didn't work.  Could it be the additional quotes in the xml payload causing issues?

Comment: Drop the Regex and simply use string functions - several of the answers below give examples on how to do it.

Comment: Is the log line one line, or several?

Comment: @user1158745 I tried to use `string` instead of readLine in my computer and it runs perfectly. So, it must be something to do with your stream reading. Beware of `\n`

Comment: @Tim, there are several log lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "`<?xml`" string begins on the next line, use this:

```
Regex request = new Regex(@"request class winmo.SyncML");
String line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 if(req.Success)
 {
  Match req = request.Match(line);
  var xmlLine = line = sr.ReadLine();
  if (null == xmlLine) break;
  string s = xmlLine.Substring(line.IndexOf("<?xml "));
 }
}
```

Or, you can improve your Regex for the newly edited example:

```
Regex request = new Regex(@"^.+request class winmo.SyncML[^\<]+(\<\?xml [^`]+)`");
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 Match req = request.Match(line);
 if(req.Success)
  string s = req.Group[1].Value;
}
```

Additionally, you can search more than one line at a time with the improved Regex:

```
Regex request = new Regex(@"^.+request class winmo.SyncML[^\<]+(\<\?xml [^`]+)");
var lines = new List<String>(5);
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 //NOTE:You'll need to make sure this gets enough of your log file to get what you want
 lines.Add(line);
 while(lines.Count>4) 
    lines.RemoveAt(0);

 Match req = request.Match(string.Join("\r\n", lines);
 if(req.Success)
  string s = req.Group[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: This improved Regex will handle if there are characters that sr.ReadLine is interpreting as EOL, because [^\<]+ will accept line breaks.

Comment: The improved reg reg seemed to find it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try using</s>

```
"<?xml"
```

instead of

```
"<?xml "
```

, I don't see that space after xml.

This question have been edited. So, If the string are formatted in several lines, you should do:

```
while((line = sr.ReadLine))!= null){

    if(req.Success){

         Math req = request.Match(line);
         if(line.contains("<?xml")){
              stirng s = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(@"<?xml"));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a space.. : `<?xml
version="1.0` -> Copied from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  if(line.Contains("<?xml "))
  {
      string s = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("<?xml "));
      // do something useful with s
  }
}
```

Comment: line.Contains doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: Then it isn't in the string.

Comment: @user1158745 I can't tell from your question -- is the log all one line or is it broken up across lines?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you have the entire log as a long string, you can use `substring(x)` with `indexof(string)` to strip everything before the area you are interested in. I'm making the assumption from your last line that everything after the initial log info is part of the wanted xml.</strike>

```
string sFullLog = ReadFullLogAsASingleString();//Could be taxing in large logs
string sXML = sFullLog.Substring(sFullLog.IndexOf("<?xml"));
```

I see that the provided sample is a single log entry, and that log entry has the xml of intrest.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex looks wrong it should be Regex request = new Regex(@"request class SyncML");

Comment: I fixed this already.  I am at a loss.  Would there be a better way to accomplish this?